# How to reuse Tower::ServiceBuilder for any given request

Tags: rust

Trying to reuse ServiceBuilder. So I don't have to recreate it for each request.

I thought I would use it like this

```
fn create_service_client()->tower::ServiceBuilder<RateLimit>{
    
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let mut svc = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .rate_limit(1, std::time::Duration::new(10, 0)) // 1 requests every 10 seconds
    .service(tower::service_fn(move |req| client.execute(req)));

    svc
    
}

let scv = create_service_client();
let res = svc.ready().await.unwrap().call(req).await.unwrap();
```

But getting Error in the return type statement: Don't know what to enter.

```
missing generics for struct `RateLimit`
expected 1 type argumentrustcE0107
service.rs(14, 12): struct defined here, with 1 type parameter: `T`
main.rs(216, 59): use angle brackets to add missing type argument
```

Or maybe I'm using tower module the wrong way altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here:

First of all, `service()` turns the builder into an actual `Service` composed of its layers while consuming the builder. If you really want to return a builder, you'll need to defer calling `service()` at a different place.

If you remove that call, you'll still end up with a different signature than you specified, i.e. the type of `tower::ServiceBuilder::new().rate_limit(1, std::time::Duration::new(10, 0))` is not `ServiceBuilder<RateLimit>` but rather `ServiceBuilder<Stack<RateLimitLayer, Identity>>`. Note that your compile error came from the `RateLimit` in your example requiring a type parameter `L`. `RateLimitLayer` does not require this.

Combined it would look something like this:

```
use tower::layer::util::{Identity, Stack};
use tower::limit::RateLimitLayer;
use tower::ServiceBuilder;
fn create_service_client() -> ServiceBuilder<Stack<RateLimitLayer, Identity>> {
    tower::ServiceBuilder::new().rate_limit(1, std::time::Duration::new(10, 0)) // 1 requests every 10 seconds
}

fn use_service() {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let svc = create_service_client().service(tower::service_fn(move |req| client.execute(req)));
    // do stuff with svc
}
```

If you need to return the RateLimit service from `use_service`, you have to be able to name the types of your closure and the return type of `client.execute()` since closures are anonymous and `client.execute()` returns an `impl Future`. One way to do so is through upcasting to trait objects:

```
type ClosureFut = Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>>>;
type ServiceClosure = Box<dyn FnMut(reqwest::Request) -> ClosureFut>;

fn return_service() -> RateLimit<ServiceFn<ServiceClosure>> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let dyn_service_fn = Box::new(move |req| Box::new(client.execute(req)) as ClosureFut);
    create_service_client().service(tower::service_fn(dyn_service_fn))
}
```

Comment: Actually, After trying to integrate your code. I found that I can't move/return svc out of use_service(). I get error : let mut svc: {unknown}
mismatched types
expected struct `Client`
   found struct `RateLimit<ServiceFn<[closure@src/main.rs:211:69: 211:99]>>`rustcE0308
main.rs(211, 69): the found closure
client.rs(1104, 10): the found opaque type

Comment: The closure is anonymous and part of the type that you want to return. Since you can't name it, you're getting an issue. You could probably work around this by boxing the closure. I'll add a more thorough explanation later.

Comment: I have edited my comment and included an example of how to return this construct. It's not the prettiest solution, but from my understanding you'd have to implement `Future` on self-defined types to get around all the boxing.